# Convert long Double to Int?

Tags: c#, rounding

Trying to convert the following value:

**9.40551020088303E+21**

to

**9405510200883031584406**

I am a but lost on how to do this? `Math.Round`, `(int)Value`.

Edit: Ok i may be wrong here, but i am trying to convert this to 9405510200883031584406 in anyway possible, it can be a string, or different type.

The final result is a tracking number and what i am starting with is what the shipping company provides me with.

Comment: Do you mean into an array of bytes, or maybe an array of ints? The maximum size of a single int is 2147483647.

Comment: Maybe check out BigDecimal..

Comment: Or if you intend it to be an integer, [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: ok i may be wrong here, but i am trying to convert this to 9405510200883031584406 in anyway possible, it can be a string, or different type.

Comment: Updated Edit on quesiton. It is a tracking number i am trying to output from the original value that the shipping company gives me.

Comment: I would say that a tracking ID should never be a number. you should import it as a string or byte[] in the first place.

Comment: Why is the number they gave you originally in a `double`?

Comment: A naive way would be to just `ToString()` it and remove the `.`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - It's hard to explain, but this is the only way i receive it, i know the end value is 9405510200883031584406, i just can't figure out how to convert it or output it to that.

Comment: Well, Your tracking number is going to be wrong, a `double` can only represent up to 15-16 digits, digits 17-22 are gone and not stored in your double and you can't get them back. You need to use something other than double to store them when you get them from the source. The closest you can get (without introducing errors) is 9405510200883030000000.

Comment: `double`s are tricky. In principle they only store 15-17 digits as Scott says. But sometimes, at the JITter's discretion they can store a full 64 bit value. Never rely on them storing that much. This behaviour can cause all kinds of horrors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the closest thing I can think of is using [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
double d = 9.40551020088303E+21;
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(d);
Console.WriteLine(bi.ToString());
```

Output would be:

```
9405510200883030261760
```

Comment: One important note that the last `0261760` is a side effect of how the double is stored, there is no way to get the original `1584406` back instead.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing isn't possible.  An int ([Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) data type has a maximum value of 2147483647.

the long ([Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) data type, can only go up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

an unsigned long ([UInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.aspx)) can go to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

The number is simply too large for any of those data types.

```
 9,405,510,200,883,031,584,406 (Your value)
     9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (Int64.MaxValue)
    18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (UInt64.MaxValue)
```

Comment: @Christian.K - thank you for the edit.  That's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert this to a string as in your question *it can be a string, or different type.* Than this should suffice.

```
        decimal value = 9405510200883031584406m;
        string str = value.ToString("F0");
```

However, this assumes you know the actual full number.  You can't convert 9.40551020088303E+21 to a more precise value, if you don't know the trailing digits.

You can see how to format in [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The fixed-point ("F) format specifier converts a number to a string of
>   the form "-ddd.ddd…" where each "d" indicates a digit (0-9). The
>   string starts with a minus sign if the number is negative. The
>   precision specifier indicates the desired number of decimal places. If
>   the precision specifier is omitted, the current
>   NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits property supplies the numeric
>   precision.